# Убрать анимацию в MPVolumeView

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Реализую MPVolumeView, все работает прекрасно за исключением того, что эта шкала громкости появляется с анимацией и я не знаю как от нее избавиться, подскажите, есть ли какое-то решение? Нашел этот пост - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27878272/mpvolumeview-animation-issue

Попробовал реализовать - не выходит (работаю на swift)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня все отработало по примеру из вашего поста. Вот код:

сабкласс mpVolumeView

```
import UIKit
import MediaPlayer

public class myVol: MPVolumeView {

    override public func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        self.xy_recursiveRemoveAnimationsOnView(self)    
    }

    func xy_recursiveRemoveAnimationsOnView(view: UIView) {
        view.layer.removeAllAnimations()
        for subview: UIView in view.subviews {
            self.xy_recursiveRemoveAnimationsOnView(subview)
        }
    }
}
```

Вью контроллер:

```
import UIKit
import MediaPlayer

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let volumeView = myVol.init(frame: CGRectMake(0, 100, 320, 100))
        self.view .addSubview(volumeView)
    }
}
```